# How to give a .net 1.1 dll a strong name in VS2003

Tags: visual-studio-2003, strongname

I have a .net 1.1 dll I need to digitally sign for a legacy project. I have created a .snk file. What steps must I take in Visual Studio to apply the signature?

**Edit**: Found this http://www.robrich.org/archive/2006/11/29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe these links will be helpfull:

[Strong name WinForms 1.1](http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/638136-strong-name)

[.NET Framework 1.1 Security Guidelines - Strong Names](http://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/.NET_Framework_1.1_Security_Guidelines_-_Strong_Names)

Answer (score 0):

prepare a key file to give strong name
**ex: sn.exe -k test.dll test.snk